# Command which put contents of a file or command into the clipboard

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, clipboard

I'd like to `cat file.txt` and put the output into the clipboard (to use it later). How can I do it, preferably by a command in `bash`?

Update: I don't want to copy content of *file.txt* to another file. I just want to put it content into clipboard (something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would do in a GUI application) to be able to past it in somewhere later.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** It seems `xclip -selection clipboard` gets the job done.

What you are looking for can be achieved on OS X using `pbcopy`.

```
cat file | pbcopy
```

Alternatively,

```
pbcopy < file
```

For linux you can find similar solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/288320/whats-like-osxs-pbcopy-for-linux) and [here](http://garywoodfine.com/use-pbcopy-on-ubuntu/). I have not tested them but if it works please let me know.

Comment: `xclip -selection clipboard` works as charm.

Comment: Thanks ! I have update that as part of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can read whole file, save it's content into a variable and operate with it:

```
CONTENT=`cat file`
...
echo "$CONTENT" > /path/to/somewhere
```

Comment: I think about system storage, something like ctrl-c but done by bash command. I don't want to copy content to another file.

Answer (score -2):

In "system storage", are you referring to your hard drive ?

Anyways, the usual bash command to do that would be:

```
cat file > path/to/storage/file
```

Comment: No, I rather think about system storage, something like ctrl-c but done by bash command.

Answer (score -2):

You could just use cat file > new_file which works like copy a file with cp.
Imho you shouldn't use cat for tasks like this.
If you just want to copy specific data in a new file, grep would be your weapon of choice. For example: grep 'keyword' file > file_with_keyword_foo

Comment: No, I rather think about system storage, something like ctrl-c but done by bash command. I don't want to copy content to another file.